# Adding User as member to AD Group through JNDI LDAP - Entry Exists

Tags: ldap, jndi

I've added a new user to AD using JNDI LDAP. And I've enable the account programmatically as well. However if I attempt to add the user to an AD Group I get and error that indicates that an Entry Already exists. See Results below for exception thrown.

"Domain Admins" is the group name but it appears that its complaining that I'm trying to re-add the group.  Here is my code.

Any example that I've found on forums does it similarly.

```
public void addUserToGroup() throws NamingException {

   String groupDN = "CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=org";

// Create the objectclass
    Attribute objClasses = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
    objClasses.add("top");
    objClasses.add("group");

// Create a entry set of attributes
    Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes();
    Attribute member = new BasicAttribute("member", getUserDN("jdoe"));

// Add these to the container
    attrs.put(objClasses);
    attrs.put(member);
    try {
        context.modifyAttributes(groupDN, DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, attrs);
} catch (Exception e) {
   LOGGER.severe("Failed to Add User to Domain Admins -- ");
}
}

public String getUserDN(String aUsername) {
    return "CN=" + aUsername + ",CN=" + "Users,DC=mydomain,DC=org";
}
```

This is the resulting exception thrown...

javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: [LDAP: error code 68 - 00000562: UpdErr: DSID-031A11E2, problem 6005 (ENTRY_EXISTS), data 0
]; remaining name 'CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=org'

Comment: You should be using MODIFY, not ADD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an attribute with values that already exist on the object: `objectClass`. 
When you use `DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE` the LDAP server assumes new values, not replacing existing values.

Why are you adding that to the modification? Just adding the `member` attribute is enough. 
Try without the `objectClass` attribute and it should work.

Comment: I was adding attribute because this user is another member. I thought that modify was changing one state or parameter for another. E.g changing an email address. Thanks I’ll give that a try when I get back to work next week.

Comment: Adding the user's DN value to the `member` attribute will make the user a member of the group. The user object should exist beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've worked w/JNDI (which is a 20 year old library BTW), but I still have something to offer here.

LDAP errors generally mean what they say, so I don't doubt the error means exactly what it says (entry already exists). This of course contradicts your code, which appears to only want to do an ldapmodify operation.

I would want to see what happens "on the wire", so how about grabbing the LDAP protocol using tcpdump or wireshark, and check to see if it's actually sending a MOD or an ADD operation? In theory this error 68 should only come from an ADD, so let's see those packets and find out what really happened.

Comment: Chris, I appreciate your willingness to assist.  I'm not well versed in tcpdump or wireshark to ensure that I capture what you're looking for.  Let me see if I can find some examples or guidance on how to get you what you're looking for.  And I'm not sure how keen our security folks are on using sniffers on the company network.

Comment: Well a "sniffer" is a pretty useful and harmless tool if used properly. You don't need to capture other machine's traffic, only your own. It is typically not possible in a normal switched environment to "sniff" other machine's traffic.

What you want to do is filter on port 389. This will reduce the capture to what's pertinent and useful. It's pretty easy to figure out how to filter.

Something like this on your LDAP box should work:

sudo tcpdump -w /path/to/outputfile.pcap port ldap or port ldaps

Then take your output.pcap file and open in Wireshark. That will illuminate a lot.

Comment: Okay this is what I captured.  I've changed IP addrs and passwords to protect the innocent....

Comment: Chris,  See section above for TcpDump output.  I could not fit it in the comment section.